# Reformat custom date from string

Tags: java, date

I‘m fetching dates which have the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.
I have these extracted as a string which would look like this:

```
String date = "2020-09-05";
```

Now I want to convert it into a `EEE, d MMM yyyy` format, so the result should be: `Sat, 5 Sep 2020`.
I tried reformatting it like this:

```
Date convertedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(EEE, d MMM yyyy).parse(date);
```

For some reason this and many tries to get around it all end up with a `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date "2020-09-05"`.

Can‘t I convert a date from a string like that? Is there a better way to reformat a string into other formats?

Comment: The code you’ve posted is invalid Java. Please double-check what you’ve written.

Comment: Try first parsing the date in its existing format, then outputting the date _that you parsed it into_ in the format you want. Internally, the data structure always formats its data the same way, and you don't know what that way is - it only matters when you tell the data structure to output its data in a specific form.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up parsing and formatting: your code is trying to *parse* a string given the format. You’re telling Java you’re expecting the date to contain the week name.

You need to first *parse* your date in the format it’s in. This will give you a date. You next need *format* your date with the desired format, which will give you a *string*:

```
final String dateString = "2020-09-05";
final Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d").parse(dateString);
final String converted = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMM y").format(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a distinction between parsing the date (turning a `String` into a `Date` or `LocalDate` class) and formatting a date (turning the `Date` or `LocalDate` class instance to a `String`).

To parse the initial string, use:

```
LocalDate convertedDate = LocalDate.parse(date)
```

To format the `convertedDate`, use:

```
String formattedDate = convertedDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy"))
```

EDIT: I am assuming you are at least on Java 8, so you can use the newer date/time classes. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

ok here's the code:

```
String sDate1="1998-12-31";
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = sdf.parse(sDate1);
 
        System.out.println("EEE, d MMM yyyy formatted date : " + new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy").format(date));
```